# Checking a given hash is in a very, very long list

Tags: algorithm, hash

I have a list of hashes. Long list. Very long list. I need to check does a given hash is in that list.

The easiest way is to store hashes in memory (in a map or a simple array) and check that. But it will require lots of RAM/SSD/HDD memory. More than a server(s) can handle.

I'm wondering is there a trick to do that in reasonable memory usage. Maybe there's an algorithm I'm not familiar with or a special collection?

Comment: A hash of hashes, perhaps? But I think we need a more detailed explanation of what you're hoping to do.

Comment: How do you "have a list" that won't fit on disk?

Comment: Which algos ARE you familiar with? Size of list? format? encoding? ...? What have you tried already? [ask] This Q is possibly off topic here. Maybe try superuser.com.

Answer (score 1):

Three thoughts-

- Depending on the structure of these hashes, you may be able to borrow some ideas from the concept of a [Rainbow Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) to implicitly store some of them.
- You could use a trie to compress storage for shared prefixes if you have enough hashes, however given their length and (likely) uniformity, you won't see terrific savings.
- You could split the hash into multiple smaller hashes, and then use these to implement a [Bloom Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter), however this a probabilistic test, so you'll still need them stored somewhere else (or able to be calculated / derived) if there's a perceived "hit", however this may enable you filter out enough "misses" that a less performant (speed-wise) data structure becomes feasible.